# How to insert javascript in a block?

Tags: 6

I would like to insert a JavaScript code in block body but I cannot save it, after 2 or 3 minutes it stop (shows a message **The connection has timed out**). I want to add `statcounter` code to a block.

EDIT 1:

I can add JavaScript in `local-host` but I can't do in server (Linux server, VPS cPanel)

Comment: What text-format options are set for the block?

Comment: Input format is Full HTML.

Comment: Have you tried the module for statcounter? http://drupal.org/project/statcounter/

Comment: Yes I am using that module, but the same problem exist !!!!

Comment: Sounds like it's a server configuration issue. Can you insert a simple javascript test without having it error out? Something like:
    (function(){
        console.log('Hello World!');
})();

Comment: Yes i can insert **(function(){ console.log('Hello World!'); })();** it.

Answer (score 1):

Create your own text filter which just does nothing which means it allows really "all" input without any filtering.

Please make sure that you allow only trusted people to use this filter since it would be easy to add XSS code.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your method but unfortunately the same error occurs!. What to do ?

Comment: Are you using a WYSIWYG editor? Sometimes they strip out script tags even if the filter allows them.